# what is the difference between c++ and MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

what is the difference between c++ and MFC(except front end designing concept)

Comment: What is the difference between a hammer and buying a television ?

Comment: What's the difference between limestone and the Leaning Tower of Piza?

Comment: fast know basics....after this we ll decide about limestone and the Leaning Tower of Piza...u r not able to ans beginers level

Comment: It's already been answered and this thread is closed so I couldn't answer, but I thought it was a perfectly nice analogy; a little better than the hammer and buying a television one since it illustrates their relationships a bit better. Had it not been closed, I would have pointed out already that MFC is a library (typically considered a very flawed one but miraculously still used today) written in C++. See the Tower of Piza analogy?

Comment: I prefer application framework rather than just a 'library'. It can be the actually the same though it is more vague to refer it to just as a library.

Answer (score 15):

[C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) is a [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) and [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) is a [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computer_science%29) written in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

Comment: @lalmay-j: `C++` **is** a language, `stl` and `MFC` **are** libraries. It is not because I **use** a hammer that I **am** a hammer. Semantic matters.

Comment: this is a book defination...i need something extra

Answer (score 11):

C++ is a programming language. 
MFC is a library written in C++ that wraps Windows API.

Have you tried Google ?

Comment: +1, because s****d questions deserve obvious answers. But what is the difference between Google and `C++` ?

Answer (score 10):

MFC is an application framework by Microsoft that is implemented in C++, which is a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

MFC is a c++ library that wraps a bunch of the windows api and provides graphic widgets.

A lot of people on SO seem to prefer using qt over mfc for gui+extras library

(plus qt is a crossplatform library (Windows/Linux/Mac/

a bunch of tiny third party desktop Operating systems you have never heard of/

win mobile<=6.5 /Symbian/Nokias high end Meego Phones(in the close future)/and a lot of work is being done on the Android port)

while mfc is windows only, meaning that if you use mfc in your application you would have to make the mfc portions be modularised away and rewrite those parts to port it to different platforms).

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443546/qt-goes-lgpl-on-windows-is-it-good-enough-to-use-instead-of-mfc